# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion

Should we just see if anybody i the Tor irc channel wants an invite to the beta (private or public) and does anybody know anybody that would be a great person to have on the site to answer questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to promote the public beta?](http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/66/how-to-promote-the-public-beta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Have a permanent link on https://www.torproject.org
- Have a permanent link on https://blog.torproject.org
- Have a permanent link irc.oftc.net #Tor
- When you start "tor", it says "Tor can't help if you use it wrong", add a link to this site there as well.
- Tor Browsers local start page should include a link to [The Tor Project's support channels](https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en) as well.
- Have a permanent link on [The Tor Project's support channels](https://www.torproject.org/about/contact.html.en) page as well.

Update: 
I agree, the link should only be shared once the page is in public beta. I didn't spend much thought on the private beta, since it's hopefully soon over anyway.

Answer (score 4):

#### This answer is now obsolete.

---

Till the site is in private beta, **please do not post site links** anywhere. Anybody trying to access the site will just get to see this:

> [image]

Right now, you should use the the invite interface on the main site to get your friends, colleagues, anyone interested in Tor, on the site:

> [image]

Comment: I agree, the link should only be shared once the page is in public beta. I didn't spend much thought on the private beta, since it's hopefully soon over anyway. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree about:

- The Tor log

I even dislike to read "Tor can't help if you use it wrong" every single time I start tor. Even if I'm not using Tor I see this warning.

Anyway, I don't think the Tor log should be cluttered with support links.

The rest I totally agree with once Stack-Exchange can be safely used over Tor. [This](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-we-get-se-to-enable-https-for-all-of-this-site) is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Some other SE sites have a [tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor) tag. I don't know if it is possible, but if someone tags a question with tor, SE could show a hint that there is Tor.SE.

Comment: That is probably not going to happen. What some users do in the Network is that they follow tags on other SE sites that they frequent and when they come across such questions, they flag it for migration.

Comment: You could always edit the tag wiki for Tor on those other sites to point out that there's Tor.SE.